# Making svg path with rounded edge responsive

Tags: javascript, svg

I am working on a svg graphic that will represent health bar in a game, thus far it is looking like this https://jsfiddle.net/8ds9hpuv

Concept is to have responsive bar that decreases / increases in width based on character health.

Right now I can't figure out how to decrease this path in width, but maintain that rounded edge on the right side all the time.

Ideally I would like to make it's height responsive as well

```html
<svg width="428" height="35">

<path d="M0 0h414.333785C423.444595 9.346449 428 15.179782 428 17.5c0 2.320218-4.555405 8.153551-13.666215 17.5H0V0z" fill="red"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson that just "crops" the graphic, it's size doesn't change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've modified the path by changing every command to lowercase (using this tool: [Convert SVG path to all-relative or all-absolute](https://codepen.io/leaverou/pen/RmwzKv) ) but I've left the last H command to uppercase since H0 is going back to x="0"

Next I'm replacing the first `h` command with the variable `healthIndicator`

I'm assuming that the tip of the arrow has only an aesthetical function.

For the sake of the demp I'm using an input type range to change the value of the `healthIndicator`. I hope this is what you need.

```js
itr.addEventListener("input",()=>{
  let healthIndicator = itr.value;
  let d = `M0,0 h${healthIndicator}c9.111,9.346,13.666,15.18,13.666,17.5c0,2.320218,-4.555405,8.153551,-13.666215,17.5H0v-35z`;
  thePath.setAttributeNS(null,"d", d);
  
})
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 550 35" >

<path id="thePath" d="M0,0
                      h414
                      c9.111,9.346,13.666,15.18,13.666,17.5
                      c0,2.320218,-4.555405,8.153551,-13.666215,17.5
                      H0z" fill="red"/>

</svg>

<input type="range" id="itr" value="414" min="0" max="500" />
```